# Determining ranking probabilities from overlapping distributions

Tags: distributions, ranking

I'm thinking about coding a ranking engine, and am unclear about how I can combine probability distributions for two (or more) entities.

I think this is easier to ask with an example.  Say I have two students, A and B, and their expected scores on an exam are distributed as follows:

$A \sim \mathcal{N}(75, 5)$

and

$B \sim \mathcal{N}(70, 5)$

How do I calculate the probability A beats B in the exam?

How would I generalise the approach to handle more students (ie for each student, determine the probability they top the exam)?

What considerations would I need to take into account for other probability distributions?

Comment: Are you willing to assume the scores to be independent? (Independence may be violated, for example, if part of the random variation is your uncertainty about how difficult the exam was, or about how effective their shared teacher was)?

Comment: $X=A-B$ is normally distributed with $\mu=5$ and $\sigma^2=10$. The answer to your question is $P(X>0)$. Hopefully that's enough of a hint.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I'm assuming the scores are independent, yes

Comment: @gammer - thanks.  That's excellent - I figured I was missing a simplification somewhere.  So the 10 is just the sum of the variances, nothing fancier?

Comment: Yes, under independence, you can just sum the variances. If there were dependence you'd have to subtract twice the covariance between the two.

Comment: For the Gaussian case, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74091 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/ seem to be duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ beats $B$ when $Y = A - B > 0$ . From the given information, and assuming independence, $Y$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu = 5$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 10$. So the probably that $A$ wins is

$$ P(Y > 0) = P \left( Z > \frac{0 - 5}{\sqrt{10}} \right) = 1 - \Phi(-1.58) = \Phi(1.58) = .943 $$