# Maths Questions - Probability distribution of choices

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, likelihood, economics

I need help with a question I am trying to work out:

Individuals have 5 choices:

- Choice 1: utility1 = alpha * R1 + beta * C1 + random_shock_1(mu=0,sig=1)
- Choice 2: utility2 = alpha * R2 + beta * C2 + random_shock_2(mu=0,sig=1)
- Choice 3: utility3 = alpha * R3 + beta * C3 + random_shock_3(mu=0,sig=1)
- Choice 4: utility4 = alpha * R4 + random_shock_4(mu=0,sig=1)
- Choice 5: utility5 = beta * C4 + random_shock_5(mu=0,sig=1)

There are some mass `M` of individuals who will choose the option that has the highest utility. However, they each have different `alphas` and `betas`, i.e. preference for consuming `R` or `C`, where `R1`, `R2`, etc are different values or `R` and `C1`, `C2` etc are different values of `C` aka constants. However the distribution of `alpha` and `beta` is known (i.e. we know the mean and sd of both).

**Is it possible to calculate the expected proportion of individuals that will choose each of the choices? and if so how?**

**EDIT:** Update below

**Random normal variables**: (`alpha` and `beta`) follow normal distributions.
e.g. $\alpha \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{\alpha},\sigma_{\alpha}^{2})$ and $\beta \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{\beta},\sigma_{\beta}^{2})$. Both `alpha`, `beta` and the `shocks` **are independent of each other**.

**Constants**: `R1`, `R2`, `C1` etc are constants.

I am ending up with 5 different distributions (e.g.`utility1`, `utility2`, ...) that are follow random normal distributions.

My question is close to [What is $P(X_1>X_2 , X_1>X_3,... , X_1>X_n)$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/what-is-px-1x-2-x-1x-3-x-1x-n?lq=1&fbclid=IwAR2vBHh2Q6Vt1STu2g8ZyAC-hKNZHGLydd6ldQsm_HpXvhrCY-nSZLlPCJw) and I have tried following this approach, but I am trying to avoid numerical integration by simulation.

I am coding this up in `fortran` and have a function to calculate the PDF and CDF of the variables, but unsure if I am still required to integrate over them from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: What would be the basis of the calculation?  What data and/or assumptions would you be using?

Comment: So I am trying to work out the expected number of individuals who would choose one option over another as simulating a large number of individuals in my situation is highly costly. In essence I am therefore trying to work out the proportion who would choose say choice 1, I am thinking the answer may lie in -> https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/what-is-px-1x-2-x-1x-3-x-1x-n?lq=1&fbclid=IwAR2vBHh2Q6Vt1STu2g8ZyAC-hKNZHGLydd6ldQsm_HpXvhrCY-nSZLlPCJw

Comment: Thanks @whuber for your comments I have added context to the answer to help clarify. I saw your response to the other question which I found most helpful, and I was wondering if you could help me in my simplified case. All random variables are independent